# jsTree: Is it possible to feed JSON map to the tree (rather than JSON array)?

Tags: javascript, jstree

Would jsTree plugin accept a map of JSON objects as input to the tree ?

We know that [jsTree requires the following format of JSON input](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) :

```
[
 { "id" : "01", "parent" : "#", "node1" : "Simple node" },
 { "id" : "02", "parent" : "#", "node2" : "node 2" }
]
```

But is it possible to provide this JSON map to the tree:

```
[
 {"01": { "id" : "01", "parent" : "#", "node1" : "Simple node" }},
 {"02": { "id" : "02", "parent" : "#", "node2" : "node 2" }}
]
```

Where keys are node ids ?

Comment: Your proposed input isn't valid JSON/JS. Did you mean to use an object instead of an array as the outermost element?

Comment: I copied the above input directly from the official site. However, my goal is to send a map of node, where node Id is the key and node's JSON object is the value.